# How to fix "Initializer provides no value for this binding element and the binding element has no default value" in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql

I am migrating an Apollo GraphQL API project written in JavaScript to TypeScript. And I am getting an error at finding a user code block, saying that:

> `var idArg: any Initializer provides no value for this binding element and the  binding element has no default value.ts(2525)`

```
  async findOne({ id: idArg } = {}) {
     // Red line here ^^^^^
    const user = await this.knex('users')
      .where('id', idArg)
      .first();

    if (!user) return;
    return user;
  }
```

Currently I added `any` to it without really knowing the actual solution, and the warning is gone:

```
  async findOne({ id: idArg }: any = {}) {
    const user = await this.knex('users')
      .where('id', idArg)
      .first();

    if (!user) return;
    return user;
  }
```

However I'd still like to know the actual solution. Should I add a `number` type instead of `any`? But when I do that, the error is:

> `Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)`.

Please help.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Depending on what you want to accomplish there are a lot of ways in which you can solve this issue.

```
// The compiler checks the object { id: '1' } and it knows it has an id property
var { id } = { id: '1' }

/* The compiler is confused. It check the object {} and it knows it doesn't have 
a property id1, so it is telling you it doesn't know where to get the value 
for id1
*/
var { id1 } = {}

/* In this case the compiler knows the object doesn't have the property id2 but
since you provided a default value it uses it 'default value'.
 */
var { id2 = 'default value' } = {}

/* In your case there are a couple of solutions: */

// 1) Provide the value in the initializer
function findOne({ id: idArg } = { id: 'value here' }) {
    console.log(id)
}
findOne()

// 2) Provide a default value
function findOne1({ id: idArg = 'value here 1' } = {}) {}

// 3) Provide initializer and type definition
function findOne2({ id: idArg}: { id?: number } = {}) {}

// 3) Do not provide initializer
function findOne3({ id: idArg}: { id: number }) {}
```

[Typescript playground link.](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/PTAEBUAsFNQYwPYFsAOBLANtATvGcBrAZ1ABcZQEAjAK2jlNAG9Q0ATALlAHIBGb0AF9QAQwB2bVowJiEAdxJpGkESXGtJKbAhQ5SATwBQANxG4W7IaAC8zDVz4DBhw8ABUEColRoCOViSIYgBmAK5E0GwAdKAAkoxw+ARkFNR0DMzC4pJKoDLyioxsCNBEYtzKIsawhiKgWjp6+hq8ADSgRAhSAWTQGBhoYgDmoPoIoe25xaXl0rJyoHIw2LCkXUPQjOSwphihNcEIuOQijA262AaGbsAmZnbsvFa2TM6uHrFiKWiBqqteyHQWFw+QUKVgaXoRRKZQqoBU1XB9W0FwMGgATKAqKFSIYiIM4LAxqFkQhjOxIqJQGxoMERKEMIxdvtuuFSt1uDS6QymSI9tBuFFDKAbndzBibDwufTGaBmQLnpkXO44l9ibg4H9wStRDq6ohQigsJRgh0EHtSGgEGIiFxRa4wLwAJSgAAK2nJNKR8tYX22vqUaD5aAAXjhDGExAwrV9goM2AB5MTQAAUFk4GgAgtgRsIXvYeD7lgrBC6mMLQJWgp0sFEMAghin2E7DM44xIk6mWw7QOiXe6yRSqdKeXK+fsI6Eo5braB24nk7w0wX2NmRrZuEWcLB+IrXmW3iBQABmfseoeDQPBsO4bJkfS6am0y8zsST6cxufxzvo5fsLirjmghcOmAD8XBiKESBUP4eaZAeypgKeoAACJdLIZznl6L5BgMN7vtGs7zp2x5-hmgFDMBDwZpB0GwQeQA)

Comment: I have a tiny issue, if I fix this issue with default value `const { rToken = undefined, theData = undefined } = { ...data };` tslint would complain for `no-unnecessary-initializer`.

Comment: Variables without a value are `undefined`, so `rToken = undefined` is unnecessary.

Comment: I already know that but I don't know why TSC throws errors without it.